# Interfacing switched resistors to an ADC input of a microcontroller

Tags: adc, interface

I am tying to interface switched resistors to a micro controller (TI CC3220 - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc3220.pdf) which uses 3.3VDC for its operation and has an ADC input range of 1.4VDC.

My requirements are

1. ADC input should not exceed 1.4 VDC
2. The switch has total 6 steps i.e 0 to 5, where in each step different resistor values are used to connect to Vcc and for 0 there wont be any connection to Vcc.
3. When the switch resistor module (3 wires to the module) is removed, ADC should always read high.

With my limited knowledge and experience, I have created a schematic as shown below. Would be great if someone can validate it or suggest other solutions to solve my use case.

Note : I do have constraints on additional components and cost, hence a cheaper and optimal solution is preferred. The ADC input impedance as per datasheet is 2.12K

Proposed Schematic (updated on 15-June-2018)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyv4BY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**ADC Calculations**
[image]

Comment: I would calculate the ADC input voltage (voltage divider equation and parallel resistors) for each option and make sure they're all under 1.4 volts. I don't think they all will be.

Comment: I would find out what the ADC input impedance is, and add that information into the question. Posing R3 to R7 values without knowing what load they're driving is a waste of time. Of course, the ADC input impedance may be 'very high', but there are types that are surprisingly low, it would be handy to know what this one is.

Comment: @Neil_UK there's a 9.8k impedance pulling the ADC input to ground, I doubt the ADC input impedance (mega-ohms?) makes much difference on top of that.

Comment: @immibis  I did calculate the ADC input voltage and they are all under 1.4 volts. Vout = Vs*R2 / (R1+R2). Did I go wrong ?

Comment: I'm glad you have it all under control then.

Comment: @Neil_UK The ADC impedance is 2.12K and the same have been added to the question.

Comment: @Neil_UK I hope removing the regulator module would also give me high value in ADC?

Comment: Why do you think removing the module would give you a high value? With 2.12k ADC input impedance, you can ignore R2, R1 will put about 0.3% of 3v into the ADC, I make that 10mV.

Comment: @Neil_UK so what do you suggest in that case ? Is my solution incorrect ?

Comment: I'm suspicious of that very low ADC input resistance. If it's really that, then yes, your solution is incorrect, as there's 2.12k of ADC in parallel with R2 and R8. Those resistors are so large they might as well not be there. Ditch R1 as well, change R3 to R7 to a tiny fraction of their values, and there's your solution. The smallest resistor required there is 2.12k * (3.3-V)/V [for V=1.4] = 2.9k, which will give full ADC scale. Do the same sum for lower voltages at the ADC for the other resistors. Without the 'module' the input will be 0, not full scale of course.

Comment: If you want more or less full scale without the module there, then R1 = 3k to 3.3v. R3 to R7 now connect to ground to pull the ADC voltage down. Note that R1 feeding the ADC 2.12k has an output impedance of  1.24k, from a voltage of 1.366V. This will help you size the pulldown resistors to lower the voltage to what you want.

Comment: There is an ADC appnote for the MCU (http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3200_ADC_Appnote) and that shows R1 and R2 as 220K and 150K. So the 2.12K impedance should be incorrect rite ?

Comment: @Neil_UK I did check with the MCU manufacturer and they confirmed that the internal impedance of 2.12K is valid. The reason being the same pins are configurable and serves multipurpose.

Comment: @Neil_UK Based on your recommendation I have recalculated the resistor values and have updated the schematic. Could you please check and help me with your feedback ? My lowest ADC voltage when my switch position is at zero would be 0.626V.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have updated the resistor values based on the common available resistor values and also the calculations are updated in my question.

Comment: I've sampled checked one of your rows and the arithmetic checks out, you appear to have calculated parallel resistors and resistor ratios correctly, so I'll assume you've 'fill-downed' the rest of them properly. My one remaining beef is language, I don't like the term 'regulator', which is why I used the more descriptive 'switched resistors'. You could use a smaller R8 to go lower in voltage, but then you'd need smaller R3-R7, which would use more current. Which is more important, coverage of the ADC range, or current consumption?

Comment: I am not too much worried about the ADC range. All I need is the ability to detect 5 steps from the switched resistors. I would be more concerned about the load on MCU which may affect its long term operation.

Comment: @Neil_UK Do you think I can measure the ADC input impedance somehow using a multi-meter ?

Comment: @Zacson Maybe measure it with a meter on ohms range, but that will only tell you impedance at one V/I, and only if the meter is the right way round. It would be better to infer it from measuring the voltage across the ADC terminals when you supply various currents through an R1, as this gives you the flexibility to check the input resistance at various points on its voltage range, just to verify that it's constant across the range. Call me suspicious if you will.

Comment: @Zacson I've just spotted that your R8 goes to a point you said was not available to your module!

Comment: @Neil_UK I was discussing further with the manufacturer and they pointed out that the ADC values are sampled (using a hold capacitor) and the 2.12K impedance is valid only during sampling time. Hence during the remaining time the 3K pull up will generate more than 1.4V which will damage the ADC pins.

Comment: They are recommending to use voltage divider R1 & R2 and and a buffer capacitor as shows in this link - http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3200_ADC_Appnote#Resistive_divider_with_buffer_capacitor_.28Recommended.29

Comment: that link shows very high impedance R1/R2. So is it the case that it's high impedance when not sampling, and draws a current equivalent to a resistance of 2.12k to ground when it's sampling? If you can't use pull-downs, then use a fixed resistive divider to deliver (say) 0.1v, and then switched pullups to get you several increments to 1.4v. Will a low voltage = low reading be OK for what happens without the module connected?

Comment: Yes, it looks like 2.12k impedance is applicable only when it is sampling. I hope I could also use a fixed resistor divider to give 1.4V without the module and use a pull down resistor inside the module to bring the voltage down to the lowest. I have updated my schematic and the calculations. Could you please have a look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial design (Proposed Schematic) which is mentioned in the question had a major drawback of spoiling the ADC pin when there is a loose contact i.e if the negative wire to the switched resistor module is disconnected, the ADC will get voltage more that the prescribed limit and spoil the pin.

Hence I may have to compromise my requirement of reading high value at ADC when module is removed as well as step 5, and handle various reading through my software itself.

Also if I was able to get a rotary switch shown by Neil_UK, it can be easily handled as per his recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using pull down resistors, you can get the following ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHmyV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the resistance of the ADC is confirmed as 2.12k, with the module removed, you get more or less full scale out of the ADC. With the module in circuit, you can switch between 0, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% and 100%.

With your schematic that uses 2 more resistors, you get 45% of FSD with the module absent, then switch between 45%, 48%, 50%, 55%, 64% and 96% of FSD. Is that some particular non-linear law you want to achieve?

Comment: I did consider your design where ADC is pulled up and adding variable pull downs. But the problem is that these regulators have no connection  for the 0 (zero) position. Hence it may not work.

Comment: Also with the module removed, I will not have R8 (1K). I have also updated my question  with the calculations. Could you please validate ?